# Does FTP support UTF Character Set?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, ftp, protocols, file-transfer

If I want to transfer some file from one system to another system which contains non-English characters. So does FTP support UTF character set ?

Comment: Do you mean the file name has Unicode chars or the content of the file?

Answer (score 7):

What we're talking about is **filename** Unicode support. To transfer a file which is UTF-8 encoded, use "binary" mode.

Although RFC 2640 extended the original FTP specification to support non-ASCII filenames, not every FTP server or FTP client supports it.

You can check your server implementation by running the following on the client's command terminal:

`FEAT`

and check for:

`UTF8`

in the response. If not, you will have to guess the 8 bit encoding of the remote side or convert your filename to ascii.

Comment: sftp> FEAT
Invalid command.

Comment: @GHuxley `sftp != ftp`. In sftp, Unicode filenames should be supported as long as your terminal or client is configured correctly.

Answer (score 3):

if you are talking about the FTP protocol it seems that it is supported.

> The FTP protocol is specified in RFC 959, which was published in 1985.
>   The FTP protocol is designed on top of the original Telnet protocol,
>   which is specified in RFC 854. The relevant sections of the Telnet
>   specification regarding FTP are those covering the Network Virtual
>   Terminal (NVT). According to RFC 854, the NVT requires the use of
>   (7-bit) ASCII as the character set. Use of any other character set
>   requires explicit negotiation. This character set only contains 127
>   different characters: English letters and numbers, punctuation
>   characters and a few control characters. Accented letters, umlauts or
>   other scripts are not contained in the ASCII character set. In order
>   to support non-English characters, the FTP specifications were
>   extended in 1999 in RFC 2640. This extension requires the use of UTF-8
>   as the character set. This character set is a strict superset of
>   ASCII, every valid ASCII character is also the same character in
>   UTF-8. The UTF-8 character set can display any valid Unicode
>   character. That includes umlauts, accented letters and also different
>   scripts. This extension is fully backwards compatible with RFC 959. As
>   long as you're using only English characters, it doesn't matter if the
>   software you are using supports RFC 2640 or not. However, if you use
>   non-English characters without using RFC 2640 compatible software,
>   there will be problems--problems which are entirely self-made by not
>   obeying the specifications.

you can read more [here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Encoding)